# Moving in a grid with certain number of steps - Unity GameDev

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, grid, chess

I built a 3D Chess game which works flawlessly. But I would like to make some changes to the movement.
The piece is supposed to walk a number of tiles. For example with a range of 3 it can either move 3 to one direction (left for example), or 2 left 1 up/down, or 1 left 2 up/down.

Which minor change do I have to implement in my code for it to work?

```
private Vector2Int[] directions = new Vector2Int[]
    {
        Vector2Int.left,
        Vector2Int.up,
        Vector2Int.right,
        Vector2Int.down,
        new Vector2Int(1, 1),
        new Vector2Int(1, -1),
        new Vector2Int(-1, 1),
        new Vector2Int(-1,- 1),
    };
    public override List<Vector2Int> SelectAvaliableSquares()
    {
        avaliableMoves.Clear();

        float range = Board.BOARD_SIZE;
        foreach (var direction in directions)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= range; i++)
            {
                
                Vector2Int nextCoords = occupiedSquare + direction * i;
                Piece piece = board.GetPieceOnSquare(nextCoords);
                if (!board.CheckIfCoordinatesAreOnBoard(nextCoords))
                    break;
                if (piece == null)
                    TryToAddMove(nextCoords);
                else if (!piece.IsFromSameTeam(this))
                {
                    TryToAddMove(nextCoords);
                    break;
                }
                else if (piece.IsFromSameTeam(this))
                    break;
            }
        }
        return avaliableMoves;
    }
```

The given code is an example of the movement of an ordinary queen.
Added a picture to demonstrate the movement.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pjn4.png)

Comment: It sounds like you want to set all positions a chess piece can move to. But your code seems to suggest you may not be dealing with strict chess rules? It looks like you only care if a piece can move a certain range, in any direction? If you ARE building a classic chess game, I would be inclined to simply include all possible moves for each piece type.

Answer (score 0):

Find the center of each chess tile and hold them all in a 2D array. Calculate which tiles the unit must traverse in accordance with its type and location. Then when you move, have it move first along the X axis and then the Y axis or vice versa. If it moves diagonally just move along both axes at the same time.